# Database check: PHP

Tags: php

I need to check my database ( containing different profile information like id, code and data) for any change in the information. 
I need to run a check if all the details are the same ( no action needed) or  if the details are different ( need to update the database with the new information).

I researched to use `mysql_num_rows($result)>0` but couldn't figure how exactly to use it, mainly if there are any changes, how will I update the database table with the new information?

Comment: from where you are getting updating values. it this different database or table.

Comment: I have got all the details from our website to the database and in situations when the client changes their details in the website, that has to be done in our database. Hope I made it clear. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the steps.

Step 1:

Get the updated values from website

```
$id
$code
$data
```

Step 2:

fire a query to to check updates

```
   $query = "select count(*) as total from table where id='$id' and code='$code',data='$data'";
    $result=mysql_query($query); 

    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Step 3:

```
if($data['total']>0){

   $update="update table set code='$code',data='$data' where id='$id'";
   mysql_query( $update);

}
```

Comment: thanks, but I am confused regarding the update query part. I am aware of the general update statement but in this case how to write the update query. An example will help me a lot.

Comment: Hi, we also need to run the $query or we will get resource id error.             $query = mysql_query("select count(*) as total from table where id='$id' and code='$code',data='$data'"); thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare two table of MYSQL. You can use SQL statement to get the "different" records.

Then you can use PHP to manipulate the records.

I recommend you to use Php PDO mysql driver , it makes life easier !